# Django 3.1.7 model custom constraint

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    source      = models.OneToOneField(Interface, related_name="source",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    destination = models.OneToOneField(Interface, related_name="destination", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notes       = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Add any additional information about this connection here.")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.source} : {self.destination}"
```

With the model above, it is possible to create a "connection" in the Django admin from A-B and from B-A. I am trying to find a way to only allow one or the other. I've looked at Meta constraints, but I'm either not getting my mind around it, or it's not possible. 'm sure there is something simple that I'm just not aware of yet. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a constraint where the `source` is always less than the `destination`. In that case your views will have to determine the minimum of the two and specify this as `source`, and the maximum of the two as `destination`.

We can enforce this constraint at the database level (given the database supports this) with:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import F, Q

class Connection(models.Model):
    # …

    def clean(self):
        if self.source_id >= self.target_id:
            raise ValidationError('The source id should be less than the destination id')
        return super().clean()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(source_id__lt=F('destination_id')),
                name='direct_acyclic_graph'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have it working now and your explanation has helped me to understand the code.